# Generic strange behaviour

Tags: c#

I met with the strange behavior of the generic. Below is the code I use for testing.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Type listClassType = typeof(List<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        Type listInterfaceType = listClassType.GetInterfaces()[0];

        Console.WriteLine(listClassType.GetGenericArguments()[0].DeclaringType);
        Console.WriteLine(listInterfaceType.GetGenericArguments()[0].DeclaringType);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]
```

I found it very strange that the second Console.WriteLine call displays a class, not an interface, because I use a generic type definition. Is this correct behaviour?

I'm trying to implement generic type inference in my compiler. Suppose I have the code below.

```
public static class GenericClass
{
    public static void GenericMethod<TMethodParam>(IList<TMethodParam> list) { }
}
```

And I want to call this method as follows:

```
GenericClass.GenericMethod(new List<int>());
```

In order to check the possibility of inference, I have to compare the type in the method signature, and type of arguments passed. But the code below returns false.

```
typeof(GenericClass).GetMethods()[0].GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == listInterfaceType;
```

Should I always use Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition for such comparisons?

Comment: Well, in each case, you are sourcing the call chain from the unbound generic List<T>, so the declaring type will always be that unbound generic type. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're confusing two different types that are both named T.  Think about it like this:

```
interface IFoo<TIFOO> { }
class Foo<TFOO> : IFoo<TFOO> {}
```

OK, what is the *generic type definition* of `Foo<int>`?  That's `Foo<TFOO>`.

What is the *interface implemented by `Foo<TFOO>`*?  That's `IFoo<TFOO>`.

What is the *type argument* of `Foo<TFOO>`?  Obviously `TFOO`.

What type *declared* `TFOO`?  `Foo<TFOO>` declared it.

What is the *type argument* of `IFoo<TFOO>`?  Obviously `TFOO`, *not* `TIFOO`.

What type *declared* `TFOO`?  `Foo<TFOO>` declared it.  *not* `IFoo<TFOO>`.  `TFOO` comes from `Foo`.

Make sense?

Comment: I don't follow the step from "What type *declared* TFOO" to why the interface type prints out as `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T]`.  in the MSDN example, names of *interfaces* are printed with *concrete types*.  I don't understand why the issue of who declares `TFOO` causes the name of a class to print out rather than the name of an interface.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx

Comment: @EricJ.: The examples in your link don't use `.DeclaringType`.

Comment: @recursive: I know, but I still don't understand the step.  I'm quite sure Eric Lippert is correct in what he says.

Comment: @EricJ.: [`DeclaringProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.declaringtype.aspx) "Gets the type that declares the current nested type or generic type parameter."  That's the part that's producing a class instead of an interface, as Eric L. explained above.

Comment: @EricJ. The MSDN example is calling `ToString()` on a type representing the `IFoo<>` interface, so it's directly asking about the interface. You are calling `ToString()` on a type representing the type that declared the `TFOO` part of `IFoo<TFOO>`. You are asking "Where did I get this TFOO from?". The interface received it, but the TFOO didn't originate there.

Comment: @recursive: I see now.  I missed that he was calling `DeclaringType`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a second answer because you added a second question:

> I'm trying to implement generic type inference in my compiler...

And thus I assume you're using reflection to build a compiler. This might not be a good idea. Reflection is much more performant now than it was back in the early days but it is still heavyweight compared to working directly with tokens. And reflection emit cannot emit every possible topology of types; it gets messed up in some scenarios involving nested struct types.

I would consider using CCI instead. We used a modified version of CCI for Roslyn.

> the code below returns false.

```
typeof(GenericClass).GetMethods()[0].GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == listInterfaceType
```

That's correct. The parameter type is `IList<TMethodParam>` and `listInterfaceType` is `IList<T>` where the `T` is the generic parameter type declared by `List<T>`, not the generic parameter type declared by `IList<T>`. Those are all different types.

> Should I always use Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition for such comparisons?

If you want to see if two generic types are both constructions of the same generic type, yes. If that's not what you want to check, then no.

This type system is complicated, so be very careful.

This is another reason to go with a token-based approach rather than a reflection-type-object based approach. When you have tokens in hand it is much easier to distinguish between a `TypeDef` and a `TypeRef`.